# PL/SQL: ORA-00936: missing expression&PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbdrop;
@C:\Users\4\Desktop\dbcreate;
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
DECLARE
   ORDER_ID     ORDERS.ODID%TYPE;
   COMPANY_NAME ORDERS.CNAME%TYPE;
   ORDER_DATE   ORDERS.ODATE%TYPE;
   CURSOR ord_cursor IS 
        SELECT ODID, CNAME, ODATE
            FROM ORDERS;
BEGIN
  for ord_cursor in 
    (select odid, cname, odate     
     from orders
     where order_date < trunc(sysdate)
       and rownum <= 5
    )
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line('Order ID   = ' || ord_cursor.odid);
    dbms_output.put_line('Order date = ' || ord_cursor.odate);
    dbms_output.put_line('Company    = ' || ord_cursor.cname);
  end loop;
END;
```

```
ORA-06550: line 2, column 24:
PLS-00302: component 'ODID' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 2, column 17:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 3, column 24:
PLS-00302: component 'CNAME' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 3, column 17:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 4, column 24:
PLS-00302: component 'ODATE' must be declared
ORA-06550: line 4, column 17:
PL/SQL: Item ignored
ORA-06550: line 6, column 29:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ODATE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 6, column 9:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 10, column 25:
PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "ODATE": invalid identifier
ORA-06550: line 10, column 6:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 16, column 45:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'ORD_CURSOR' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 16, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 17, column 45:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'ORD_CURSOR' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 17, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
ORA-06550: line 18, column 45:
PLS-00364: loop index variable 'ORD_CURSOR' use is invalid
ORA-06550: line 18, column 5:
PL/SQL: Statement ignored
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: Simple typo: you have a SELECT statement in parentheses, in the FOR loop. You have an errant comma after the last column name, `odate`, in the `SELECT` clause. Oracle doesn't expect a comma right before the `from` keyword - if you have that comma, it is expecting one more column expression. Since it doesn't find it, it throws that error. Delete the comma and you should be fine.

Comment: I did as you told, but there are more errors coming out.

Comment: That is fine - you solved one problem. I am not going to try to fix all the problems - I don't have your data, so I can't reproduce the problems.

Comment: Yeah, thank you! I have edited the problem already.

Comment: The error is telling you that your `orders` table - presumably being created by the `dbcreate` script - doesn't have a column called `odid`. (It's coming from the local variable declaration, as the line/char in the error points to that; you don't actually need the declare part, but it'll still error from the column reference in the implicit cursor...)

Comment: A potentially related problem: you don't need the `DECLARE` section. You have an implicit cursor created in the parentheses, so you don't need to declare a cursor. The variable `ord_cursor` in your `for` loop refers to the record that is assigned, and it is implicitly created by your cursor for loop. (I'd name it `ord_rec` to make it clear). The other variables in the `DECLARE` section are not used anywhere since you are printing the record's fields. Just remove everything before `BEGIN`.